# set elem id in React without JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I can use this JSX snippet to create an element containing an input element with id="searchBar"

```
const searchDiv = (
   <div>
     <input id="searchBar"/>
   </div>
);
```

how would I do it without using JSX?

I think it should be like this:

```
const searchDiv = (
      React.createElement(div,
      React.createElement(input, {id:"searchBar"}),
      )
);
```

what am I doing wrong here?

I've tried putting "id" in quotes.

What I really need is better documentation of the parameters that can go into

```
React.createElement()
```

Comment: Documentation is [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement), what about that is lacking?

Comment: go away @Hamms unless you're here to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
const searchDiv = React.createElement(
   'div',
   {},
   React.createElement('input', {id: "searchBar"})
)
```